# Displaying xml item in a listbox (XlmSerialiser)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following deserialize method:

```
   public static List<Enquete> GetAlleEnquetes()
    {
    XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Questions.xml"));

    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Enquete>), new XmlRootAttribute("enqueteSysteem"));
        return (List<Enquete>)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
    }

}

public static Enquete GetEnqueteName(string name)
{
    foreach (Enquete e in GetAllEnquetes())
    {
        if (e.Name == name)
            return e;  
    }
    return null;     

}
```

Which works properly (this code is located in a class withing App_data).

Next i want to retrieve all the names and display them in a listbox.

But how exactly do i retrieve the names?  `<Enquete Name ="">` and list all of those in my listbox control? (through the asp.cs file)

My xml structure looks like this:

```
<enqueteSystem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Enquete Name="test">
     <Questions>
       <Question QuestionText="testtest" QuestionType="na"></Question>
     </Questions>
   </Enquete>
</enqueteSystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve all the names

```
var serializedEnquetes = XDocument.Parse(serializedXml);
IEnumerable<string> names = serializedEnquetes
                                .Descendants("Enquete")
                                .Attributes("Name")
                                .Select(a => a.Value);
```

Then simply use the 'names' collection as a source for your listbox